# is it wrong? TextView displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayTextView);

Tags: android, textview, assign

Everyone, I am a newbie to android development. Now I have a question that cannot be solved by myself. Anything wrong with the code below(especially the line marked in the code)?

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.amaker.ch02.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private TextView displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayTextView);  <--Possibly this line

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        displayTextView.setText("change in the code"); 
    }
}
```

Run, and i got a message in AVD: ***The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.*** But if i dont assign displayTextView immediately after declaration, IOW i change the code as follows, then everything goes well.

```
package com.amaker.ch02.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private TextView displayTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayTextView);
        displayTextView.setText("change in the code"); 
    }
}
```

Why? Any difference with the two codes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The TextView is not part of the activity's view hierarchy until after you call `setContentView(R.layout.main)`. When you declare the variable like this:

```
private TextView displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayTextView);
```

the view does not yet exist, so `displayTextView` gets set to `null`. Then you are getting a `NullPointerException` when you try to call `setText()` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: +1. findViewById defaults to the Activity's layout. Since the activity's layout is "initialized" in setContentView

Answer (score 0):

Because the text view is not set to the content of your activity and you are trying to find it.. the text view is binded to your activity only in on create when you call `setContentView()` after you set a content to your activity, you can get `View`s from that content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{     

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */     
      private TextView displayTextView;
    @Override     
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    
        displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayTextView);         
        displayTextView.setText("change in the code");      
     }
    }
```